# Laravel: LAST_INSERT_ID() is 0 after insert?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have the following working query:

```
$year         = 2019;
$month        = 6;
$stmt         = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO officeRechNr (jahr,monat,zahl) VALUES (?,?,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE zahl = LAST_INSERT_ID(zahl+1)');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $year, $month);
$stmt->execute();
echo $db->insert_id;
```

The table `officeRechNr` has the unique primary index `['jahr','monat']` and `zahl` is an `index` with `autoincrement`.

So if  the table `officeRechNr` is empty, and I execute the code 5 times, then the output is

> 1, 2, 3,  4, 5

I tried to translate this in Laravel 5 with

```
\DB::select(DB::raw('INSERT INTO officeRechNr (jahr,monat,zahl) VALUES (?,?,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE zahl = LAST_INSERT_ID(zahl+1)'),[2019,6]);

return DB::select('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
```

However, if I execute this code 5 times I get

> 0, 2, 3,  4, 5

Although it returns `0` after the first insert, there is a 1 in the `zahl` column.

[image]

Why does my Laravel Code not return 1 after the first insert?

Comment: Why not use `DB::insert` instead? Also you're putting in the values for `zahl`, why make it an autoincrement field?

Comment: @user2693053 I can't use `DB::insert` because I want to use `DB::raw`. Putting the `zahl` column as `autoincrement` is necessary, so that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns its value (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html).

Comment: that makes sense.

Comment: I honestly can't think of a reason why this would happen. The [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id](manual) does state: _If expr is given as an argument to LAST_INSERT_ID(), the value of the argument is returned by the function and is remembered as the next value to be returned by LAST_INSERT_ID()._, may be something to consider, but I don't really see how that could be a problem.

Comment: @user2693053 interesting idea. I just checked and found that the problem is `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and it does not have anything to do with Laravel... I have to edit my question a bit now. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @user2693053 I didn't want to delete the Laravel problem, so I have now opened a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47440180/last-insert-id-is-unequal-to-db-insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: `SELECT_LAST_INSERT_ID()` will not work on first insert(see example below). Instead use `\DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();`

---

**Why `SELECT_LAST_INSERT_ID()` will not work on first insert**

Its stated here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

> With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit)
>   value representing the first **automatically generated** value
>   successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the
>   most recently executed INSERT statement.

With **automatically generated** is meant that the auto column increased itself and is not set by me.

Example:

Image a table `test` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
       id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
       );
```

Now

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO test ( id, name ) VALUES (33, "ADAM")';
$db->query($sql);
echo $db->insert_id;
$result =  $db->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
print_r($row);
```

returns

> 33
>
> array('SELECT_LAST_INSERT_ID()' => 0);

Doing the same with

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO test (  name ) VALUES ("Eba")';
```

returns

> 1
>
> array('SELECT_LAST_INSERT_ID()' => 1);

So in the first statement:

```
$stmt         = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO officeRechNr (jahr,monat,zahl) VALUES (?,?,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE zahl = LAST_INSERT_ID(zahl+1)');
```

`SELECT_LAST_INSERT_ID()` is 0 because the AI key was not **automatically generated**, although the id is `1` in the table. The reason why it works for the sequent numbers is

> If expr is given as an argument to LAST_INSERT_ID(), the value of the
>   argument is returned by the function and is remembered as the next
>   value to be returned by LAST_INSERT_ID().