# LAST_INSERT_ID() is unequal to $db->insert_id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
$year         = 2019;
$month        = 6;
$stmt         = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO officeRechNr (jahr,monat,zahl) VALUES (?,?,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE zahl = LAST_INSERT_ID(zahl+1)');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $year, $month);
$stmt->execute();
echo $db->insert_id;

echo '|';

$sql = 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as number';
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['number'];
echo '<br>';
```

The table `officeRechNr` has the unique primary index `['jahr','monat']` and `zahl` is an `index` with `autoincrement`.

If  the table `officeRechNr` is empty, and I execute the code 3 times, then the output is

> 1|0
>
> 2|2
>
> 3|3
>   ...

Why is `LAST_INSERT_ID()` zero after insert, but correct after upgrade? 
How do I need to change my query, so that both functions output the same number (1) after insert?

---

Edit: The purpose of the code is that I need for each invoice that is created in a specific year and month a third unique ascending number. So for example if we have 7 invoices in the year 2015 and month May (3),then I would have the folloing numbers

```
2015-3-1
2015-3-2
2015-3-3
2015-3-4
2015-3-5
2015-3-6
2015-3-7
```

So in the row in the database I have stored the current invoice number and with the SQL command presented above I can get the next number. The only reason why the column `zahl` is an `autoincrement` field is that the number is returned by `insert_id` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html). Its also necessary to get it through `insert_id` in case that people create simultaneously invoices.

Comment: I don't think Codeigniter activerecord works with `$db->prepare()` statements. Maybe try `$db->insert()`, I don't think you need the "ON DUPLICATE" if you use AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: @VincentDecaux Hi thanks for your respond. I do not use Codeigniter. The Auto_INCREMENT is only so that `$db->insert_id;` or `LAST_INSERT_ID()` return that field, see (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html). I will write that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `LAST_INSERT_ID(...);` with an argument doesn't return the generated ID but instead set the given value in the "memory" of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and returns it. So, in your first execution no auto incremented ID was generated (you provided the value by yourself) and `LAST_INSERT_ID()` return `0`. In your following executions you save the value `next+1` in the internal storage of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, which returns the value. This behavior is described in the MySQL in [12.14 Information Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> If expr is given as an argument to LAST_INSERT_ID(), the value of the argument is returned by the function and is remembered as the next value to be returned by LAST_INSERT_ID().

In fact, you can skip the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` call and work without it.

```
INSERT INTO
    officeRechNr (jahr,monat,zahl)
VALUES
    (?,?,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE zahl = zahl+1
```

This will insert the row (with the given value) or increase the counter.

If you want the current counter for a given year and month you run a simple SELECT statement. Keep in mind that you might need transactions or locks because a different client could increase the counter before you fetched it with the SELECT statement.

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't get it. The description says: `If expr is given as an argument to LAST_INSERT_ID(), the value of the argument is returned by the function`. So on the first call where `zahl` is zero, `expr = zahl +1 = 1` and thus `LAST_INSERT_ID()` should indeed return 1, or am I missing anything?

Comment: @Adam In the first call the UPDATE part isn't called because the row has been inserted. Therefore the `LAST_INSERT_ID(...)` function hasn't been called. In the second call the argument will be "1+1" and so the function return `2`.

Comment: Allright I understood it now :)! It says in the docs `LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a value representing the first __automatically__ generated value`. This means `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is not affected when by `INSERT ..` , `UPDATE ..`, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE ..` when you specify the `autocolumn` and that is what I did. That is where $db->insert_id is different. This also stores the autocolumn id when you specify the `autocolumn` instead of **autogenerating** it..